# Error en android studio Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060056

Tags: android-studio

Soy nuevo aquí, saludos. Me sale el error indicado en el log cuando intento lanzar la aplicación en mi móvil y no la ejecuta, desde android studio. En el emulador si se ejecuta con normalidad. Es cuando intenta reproducir una animación que he creado.
Log:
    Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060056
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1384)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:837)
        at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:458)
        at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:17340)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setBackgroundResource(AppCompatImageView.java:124)
        at com.MainActivity.animate(MainActivity.java:22)
        at com.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6367)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2404)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2511) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:165) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1375) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5621) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:684) 
Xml:

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/s1" android:duration="250" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/s2" android:duration="250" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/s3" android:duration="250" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/s4" android:duration="250" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/s5" android:duration="250" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/s6" android:duration="250" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/s7" android:duration="250" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/s8" android:duration="250" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/s9" android:duration="250" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/s10" android:duration="250" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/s12" android:duration="250" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/s12" android:duration="250" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/s13" android:duration="250" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/s14" android:duration="250" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/s15" android:duration="250" />
```

MainActivity:
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    animate();
}


private void animate(){
    ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagen);
    imgView.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
    imgView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.frame_animation);

    AnimationDrawable frame = (AnimationDrawable) imgView.getBackground();
    if(frame.isRunning()){
        frame.stop();
    }else{
        frame.stop();
        frame.start();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

El LogCat indica en que lineas de código se tiene el problema:

> widget.AppCompatImageView.setBackgroundResource(AppCompatImageView.java:124)
>   at com.MainActivity.animate(MainActivity.java:22) at
>   com.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)

el problema es que estas cargando en un `ImageView` una "imagen" la cual no existe o en realidad no es una imagen!

```
imgView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.frame_animation);
```

Solo puedes cargar una imagen, si tratas de cargar una animación no es correcto usar este método.

> [setBackgroundResource()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setBackgroundResource(int)) Establece el fondo a un recurso dado. El
>   recurso debe referirse a un objeto Drawable o 0 para eliminar el
>   fondo.

Para cargar una animación usa [setAnimation()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAnimation(android.view.animation.Animation)),y guarda tu animación dentro del directorio `/anim` y no en `/drawable`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ejemplo:

```
 Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.frame_animation);
 imageView.setAnimation(anim);
```